# Need help with filling out a form in French

Tags: abréviations

I am filling in a form in French, but I do not speak the language. With online dictionaries I got through most of it, and am now left with this part:

Né(e) le: ……………………

A: ………………No Départ.: ……… Pays: ……………………

I suppose "Né(e) le" is the date of birth, and "Pays" the country of birth, correct? What are the other two?

Also: There was a "nom usuel" to be filled out, and separately the first and family name. Is "nom usuel" just the way one wants to be called?

Thanks for help!

Comment: **A** (fill in with the name of the town where you were born) **N° *Départ*** stand for *Département* (where you were born) . It is an administrative subdivision, and they want the number, not the name. it might not have an equivalent in your check this article [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_(country_subdivision)). You have found out correctly for the rest.

Comment: @Laure Thank you so much!

Comment: Laure, you should turn into a question, to remove this question from the queue of unanswered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just transform @None's (Laure) comment into an answer in order to remove this question from the queue of unanswered ones (as @Quidam suggests). [A couple of things were added.]

> **A (or À)** (fill in with the name of the town where you were born) **N° Départ.** [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_(country_subdivision))] stands for Département (where you were born).
>
> The final dot makes clear it is not the word départ but an abbreviation of a word starting with départ-. (thanks @jlliagre)
>
> '*Département*' is an administrative subdivision, and they want the number, not the name. It might not have an equivalent in your country. Check this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_(country_subdivision)) on Wikipedia. You have found out correctly for the rest.

[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_(country_subdivision))] An alternate abbreviation for *département* can be *dép.*. [Thanks @SébastienC for pointing it out.]

Another one is *dépt.* which is less ambiguous. [Thanks @jlliagre for pointing it out.]

[Cf. http://www.guide-typographie.com/abreviations.htm]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the correct abbreviation for **département**  is *dép.*
**Départ** means departure in French.

Comment: The final dot makes clear it is not the word *départ* but an abbreviation of a word starting with *départ-*. Note also that *dépt* is a common and less ambiguous alternate abbreviation for *département*.

Comment: Indeed, thanks @jlliagre.