# Emploi de "mascotte"

Tags: usage, registre

En voyant ce [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mascotte&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmascotte%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmascotte%3B%2Cc0) et le [lemme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mascotte) sur Wikipédia, je me suis dit qu'on pouvait utiliser couramment *mascotte*. Or, en parlant avec quelques locuteurs natifs (pré-ados, ados et adultes), j'ai été surpris par le nombre des personnes qui n'en connaissent pas le sens :

> Un être (le plus souvent, un animal) ou une chose servant de **symbole, d'emblème** (ou de porte-bonheur) à un groupe de personnes, une équipe de sport, une institution ou une entreprise.

Peut-on employer couramment le mot "mascotte" en français avec cette signification ?

Comment: @Personne Pour donner une réponse, merci d'utiliser la fonctionnalité prévue à cet effet. Comme cela se produit très souvent en ce moment malgré plusieurs indications de ma part, j'ai supprimé ton commentaire.

Comment: @Reyedy — Tu as le droit de ne pas lire mon profile … et d’effacer un commentaire par principe, sans savoir s’il était utile pour les lecteurs du site ou à Dimitris… sans non plus utiliser Causette … as-tu l’accord des autres modérateurs, les anciens comme les nouveaux ?

Comment: @Personne En effet, je n'ai pas vu ton commentaire...

Comment: Il renvoyait à CNRTL et son origine militaire avec qqch comme « personnage ou animal considéré comme bienfaisant et emblématique pour une personne ou pour un groupe »

Comment: @Personne Merci beaucoup ! Si tu n'as pas envie de le donner comme une réponse (j'ai lu ton profil:-)!) quelqu'un pourrait le faire. J'ai déjà fait ça une couple de fois comme dans cette réponse : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39976/need-help-with-filling-out-a-form-in-french/42383#42383

Comment: Laure a été un modèle pour moi … peut-être une affinité générationnelle :-)

Comment: @Personne On augmente notre impact chez FSE grâce à votre générosité :-)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110409/discussion-between-personne-and-dimitris).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En français de France, on utilise volontiers ce terme. Si tu n’es pas en France, peut-être est-ce pour cette raison ?

Par ailleurs, je tiens à souligner qu’il y a le plus souvent une dimension physique à ce terme (là où emblème a une dimension symbolique). Par exemple, on dira (plutôt que d’utiliser le terme mascotte) :

> L’**emblème** de la Bretagne est l’hermine.

Et, en parlant d’une personne déguisée en hermine dans un événement, on dira :

> Voilà la **mascotte** de la Bretagne.

Pour les clubs de sport par exemple, le nom de la mascotte diffère parfois du nom de la chose qu’elle représente. On différencie donc bien ici la mascotte, qui est une sorte d’incarnation physique du club, et l’emblème qu’elle représente.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne suis pas certain que ces personnes n'aient pas dans leur « bibliothèque mentale » ce sens, à moins qu'on ne t'ait explicitement dit que Tony the Tiger, Sam le Toucan ou des personnages tels que [Youppi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youppi!) ou Zabivaka n'étaient pas des mascottes, je soupçonne plutôt que ces interlocuteurs n'auraient pas instinctivement décrit ces personnages comme des « symboles ou emblèmes. » Après tout, les compagnies depuis des années déploient tous les efforts possibles pour que ce genre de mascotte ne soit pas perçu comme étant commercial ou, pire encore, publicitaire.